# How to stop toggleClass() on push of the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are 4 divs on my page and a button. If you click on a div, it togglesClass.

On button click I want all the divs that had been highlighted to stay highlighted, but I do not want any more divs to toggleClass after the button has been clicked.

Is there a way to do this?

My code goes like this:

```
function submit() {
//this is the function I do not know how to define
};

function choose() {
    $('.options').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    });
    return;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div class="options">option1</div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="options">option2</div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="options">option3</div>');
    $('body').append('<div class="options">option4</div>');
    $('body').append('<button onclick=submit()>Submit</button>');
    choose();
});
```

I have been looking for a way to stop the choose() function. Creating a variable goOn and changing its value to false on button click, plus the bit of code below didn't help.

```
var goOn = true;
while (goOn) {
    choose();
};
```

Comment: Instead of toggleClass, why dont you use addClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unbind the click event with `.off()`:

```
function submit() {
    $('.options').off('click')
};
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9DHDg/)**

Comment: What if I have 'hover' instead of 'click'? Why wouldn't it work? It worked perfectly for 'click' but not for 'hover'.

Comment: Because hover is really a jQuery shortcut to the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Comment: And is there a way to do the same thing if I have 'hover'?

Comment: `$('.options').off('mouseenter mouseleave')`

Answer (score 1):

Use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method if you want bound event handler to be called only once. E.g.

```
 $('.options').one( "click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    });
```

Comment: I don't think this is what is asked. He wants to be able to toggle the class (not just once, possibly many times) until the button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the event listener (this is compatible with older and the latest versions of jQuery):

```
function choose() {
    $('.options').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    });
    return;
};
choose();
$('button').click(function () {
    $('.options').unbind('click');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69rxF/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function choose() {
$('.options').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    if ($('.options').length == $('.highlighted').length)
    {
      $('.options').off('click');
    }
});
return;};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G7mb3/2/

Comment: Did not work for me. I can still toggle classes even after I clicked the button

Answer (score 1):

Boolean, full example:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/T98qL/)</kbd>

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

ok2toggle = 1;

$('body').append('<div class="options">option1</div>');
$('body').append('<div class="options">option2</div>');
$('body').append('<div class="options">option3</div>');
$('body').append('<div class="options">option4</div>');
$('body').append('<button id="mySubmit">Submit</button>');

choose();

function choose() {
    $('.options').click(function() {
        if (ok2toggle==1)
            $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    });
    return;
};

$('#mySubmit').click(function() {
    ok2toggle = 0;
});

}); //END document.ready
```

OR, change submit sub to this to use Submit button as a toggle:

[Revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T98qL/1/):

```
$('#mySubmit').click(function() {
    ok2toggle = !ok2toggle;
});
```

---

***Note that an ID was added to your submit button, and inline javascript (never a good idea) was removed.***